# Dynamically enforce object and field level security?

Tags: apex, permissions, crud

I am building a dynamic data table in lightning and trying to enforce object and field level security for it, but I'm having some issues.

Here is my code to check for object access.

```
String[] objects = new String[]{'Broker__c'};
List<Schema.DescribeSobjectResult> results = Schema.describeSObjects(objects);
boolean objectVisible = results[0].isAccessible();
System.debug('Object visible: ' + objectVisible);
```

`Broker__c` would be a String variable but for this example, I hard-coded it. I tested this on a profile that didn't have modify all data or view all data enabled and I turned access to the Broker object completely off. However, when I pull up the data table and look at my debug logs, Object Visible is always true. This only seems to be an issue if the object is dynamic. For instance, using the code below returns the correct boolean value.

```
boolean objectVisible = Schema.sObjectType.Broker__c.isAccessible();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this behavior is generically reproducible. Can you try `Schema.getGlobalDescribe('Broker__c').getDescribe().isAccessible()` and see if it also returns an unexpected result?

Comment: Hi Adrian, I used that code snippet, but I get the following error when trying to save the class. "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Schema.getGlobalDescribe(String)"

Comment: Sorry, `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Broker__c')...`

Comment: I used the code below but now I get the error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Schema.SObjectType].isAccess‌​ible()"

     boolean objectVisible = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Broker__c').getDescribe().isAccess‌​ible();

Comment: That seems like the error you would get if you dropped the `getDescribe` call from that code snippet.

Comment: getDescribe() is there though

Comment: Seems like you snuck some invisible characters in there somehow. Re-type the method name or copy-paste it from [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) and it should work out better for you.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I retyped it and it works fine. Do you have an example for checking field security?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try getting the `DescribeSObjectResult` directly from the global describe and checking against that:

```
SObjectType sObjectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('MyObject__c');
Boolean isMyObjectAccessible = sObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible();
```

If you want to also check which fields are accessible, you can get them from the `fields` map.

```
Set<SObjectField> accessibleFields = new Set<SObjectField>();

SObjectType sObjectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('MyObject__c');
for (SObjectField field : sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values())
    if (field.getDescribe().isAccessible())
        accessibleFields.add(field);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well We have an Amazing library that does FLS and sharing checks for us in APEX which is of enterprise grade. ESAPI. 
The access control module provides functionality to enforce the Force.com built in access control mechanisms: CRUD, FLS, and Sharing. As described in the apex documentation, apex classes execute in system context and not in the current user context. This is why the platform can't enforce any of the security models. For more details please see Enforcing CRUD and FLS. This ESAPI module allows apex classes execute statements such as insert object; as if operating in user context.

https://github.com/forcedotcom/force-dot-com-esapi

Comment: Thanks for this Pranay. I will check it out, but why does my code above not work? From all the documentation I've seen from Salesforce, that's how you're supposed to check for object accessibility.